# Trapping clicks on list items with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nested list that I am using to show collapsible items.  The problem is that I cannot seem to distinguish between a click on the parent and a click on the child.  Here is my code:

```
function myFunction(elmnt) {

var child=(elmnt.firstElementChild||elem.firstChild)


if (child.style.display == 'block') {

child.style.display = 'none'
} else {
child.style.display = 'block'    
child.style.listStyleType = "none";
}

}
```

Here is my nested list of items:

```
<li class="List" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                Recently Viewed
                <ul class="Items">
                    <div>
<table class="myclass">
<tr>
<td class="title_check"><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png">Name</td>
<td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png">Report Type</td>
<td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png">Modified On</td>
<td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png">Description</td>
</tr></table>

<table class="myclass">
<tr>
<td class="check"><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td class="name">Report 1</td>
<td ></td>
<td ></td>
<td ></td>
</tr></table>

<table class="myclass">
<tr>
<td class="check"><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td class="name">Report 2</td>
<td ></td>
<td ></td>
<td ></td>
</tr></table>



                </ul>
```

The problem is when I click on the check box next to one of the nested child items, the function gets called and it collapses the parent.  Is there a way I can distinguish between a click on the parent and a click on the child item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe7Ljxsk/)

Modified your JS and HTML code to include the `click` function on a `span` instead of `li`.

HTML Code:

```
<ul>
<li class="List" >
    <span onclick="myFunction(this)">Recently Viewed</span>
                <ul class="Items">
                    <div>
<table class="myclass">
<tr>
    <td class="title_check"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png"/>Name</td>
    <td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png"/>Report Type</td>
    <td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png"/>Modified On</td>
    <td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png"/>Description</td>
</tr></table>

<table class="myclass">
<tr>
    <td class="check"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
<td class="name">Report 1</td>
<td ></td>
<td ></td>
<td ></td>
</tr></table>

<table class="myclass">
<tr>
    <td class="check"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
<td class="name">Report 2</td>
<td ></td>
<td ></td>
<td ></td>
</tr></table>

    </div>
    </ul>
    </li>
                </ul>
```

JS Code:

```
function myFunction(elmnt) {
var child = elmnt.nextElementSibling;
//var child=(elem.firstElementChild||elem.firstChild)


if (child.style.display == 'block') {

child.style.display = 'none'
} else {
child.style.display = 'block'    
child.style.listStyleType = "none";
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this, but the problem is that my Javacript line that tries to see the display state of the children (block vs. none) doesn't work because the Span doesn't have children.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your change to the script.  I added that and it worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the function controlling the parent, collect the "event" object, and see if event.target refers to the parent. If it does, execute the function. If it refers to a checkbox, then don't execute.

```
<li class="List" id="item-list" onclick="myFunction(this, event)">//pass event to your function

function myFunction(elmnt, event) {
if(event.target.id !== "item-list") {
    return;
}

var child=(elmnt.firstElementChild||elem.firstChild)


if (child.style.display == 'block') {

child.style.display = 'none'
} else {
child.style.display = 'block'    
child.style.listStyleType = "none";
}

}
```

Comment: how do i do this?  I tried putting in alert(event.target) in the function but this did not work.

Comment: I put "alert(elmnt.className)" to see the className of the object when it gets clicked.  The class Name is "List" when I click both the Parent and the Child.

Comment: So even though I am clicking on the child, it is the parent that is getting the event.  I don't know if there is any way around this.

Comment: Just realized you were already passing the "this" object, so I edited my answer using that instead.